# Show multiple error messages only once during validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a simple multichoice answer form on one of my pages. All of the fields are required, and I am using validation to check that they are all completed and correct.

When I return my error message, I don't want to say which answer was wrong, I want them to figure this out for themselves. But it is OK to tell them which specific question they haven't filled out.

Given this, I've built my validator like so:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'multi1' => 'required|in:b',
            'multi2' => 'required|in:a',
            'multi3' => 'required|in:c',
            'multi4' => 'required|in:b',
            'multi5' => 'required|in:c',
            'multi6' => 'required|in:a',
            'multi7' => 'required|in:c',
            'multi8' => 'required|in:c',
            'multi9' => 'required|in:a',
            'multi10' => 'required|in:b',

        ], [
            'multi1.required' => 'The first question is empty!',
            'multi2.required' => 'The second question is empty!',
            'multi3.required' => 'The third question is empty!',
            'multi4.required' => 'The fourth question is empty!',
            'multi5.required' => 'The fifth question is empty!',
            'multi6.required' => 'The sixth question is empty!',
            'multi7.required' => 'The seventh question is empty!',
            'multi8.required' => 'The eighth question is empty!',
            'multi9.required' => 'The ninth question is empty!',
            'multi10.required' => 'The tenth question is empty!',

            'multi1.in' => 'At least one of your answers was incorrect. Please review them and resubmit.',
            'multi2.in' => 'At least one of your answers was incorrect. Please review them and resubmit.',
            'multi3.in' => 'At least one of your answers was incorrect. Please review them and resubmit.',
            'multi4.in' => 'At least one of your answers was incorrect. Please review them and resubmit.',
            'multi5.in' => 'At least one of your answers was incorrect. Please review them and resubmit.',
            'multi6.in' => 'At least one of your answers was incorrect. Please review them and resubmit.',
            'multi7.in' => 'At least one of your answers was incorrect. Please review them and resubmit.',
            'multi8.in' => 'At least one of your answers was incorrect. Please review them and resubmit.',
            'multi9.in' => 'At least one of your answers was incorrect. Please review them and resubmit.',
            'multi10.in' => 'At least one of your answers was incorrect. Please review them and resubmit.',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/application/multichoice')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }
```

The only issue with this is that if one or more of the questions are incorrect, then the same error message, `At least one of your answers was incorrect. Please review them and resubmit.`, is repeated multiple times.

I'm printing it out on the page like so:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <p><b>There are some errors with your answers:</b></p>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Is there an easy way to prevent this from happening or to only print it out once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of the previous error and only show an error
if it's not the same as the previous error:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <p><b>There are some errors with your answers:</b></p>
        <ul>
            {{--*/ $prev = null; /*--}}
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                @if ($prev != $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endif 
                {{--*/ $prev = $error; /*--}}
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: I had to change the declaration of `$prev` to `{{--*/ $prev = null; /*--}}`, but other than that this worked perfectly!